OpenAI API doesn’t allow two concurrent runs on same assistant
I loop through the getFromPdf function like so:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
var1= row['var1']
var2= row['var2']
aiapi.getFromPdf(var1, var2, 'asst-zxc123', 'file-zxc123')

For the first item in the df this works just fine and I get the desired reply! However, from the second item onward it keeps failing.
def getFromPdf(var1, var2, assistantid, fileid):
client = OpenAI()

thread = client.beta.threads.create(
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content":
            f"Logic with varable {var1} and {var2} based on the attached file!"
            ,
            "attachments": [
                {"file_id": fileid, "tools": [{"type": "file_search"}]}
            ],
        },
    ]
)

run = client.beta.threads.runs.create_and_poll(
    thread_id=thread.id,
    assistant_id=assistantid,
    instructions="Address the user as john doe.",
)

if run.status == 'completed': 
    messages = client.beta.threads.messages.list(
    thread_id=thread.id
    )
    print(messages)
else:
    print(run.status)

I have exactly the same issue when streaming and using class EventHandler(AssistantEventHandler).
How do I use the same assistant twice in a row without failure?
